# PolymerFire server TimeStamp

Tags: timestamp, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am trying to retrieve firebase server timestamp (firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) in a polymer project using polymerfire. Is that possible and how ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this place holder value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-rest-server-values): {".sv":"timestamp"}
For example when you push your data:

```js
this.$.post.ref.push({
  title:"Hello",
  body:"Hello world",
  time:{".sv":"timestamp"}
 })
```